# Display files inside a folder on a menu

Tags: macos, cocoa

How can I create a menu that displays a list of files and other folders inside a folder?

Comment: i don't tried anything yet. I want a code to do it.

Comment: You can use NSFileManager to get the files in a directory and then NSMenu to create a menu.

Comment: Yes but i want the code to do it using the NSFileManager